# If Net torque is zero what will happen to the net force on that object for Rotational Motion?

Tags: rotational-dynamics

Will the Net force be zero or non zero ?
Would really help if given an example.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What is the condition of motion for the body? Is it pure rotation (about COM) or general rotation with the COM translates and the body rotates about the COM? Please provide details to this question to make it answerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If Net torque is zero what will happen to the net force on that object
> for Rotational Motion?

If the net torque is zero on a rotating object, the object will rotate at constant angular velocity (angular acceleration is zero). The line of action of any net force acting on the object must be through the center of mass in order for the net torque to be zero. That net force will cause linear acceleration of the center of mass of the object without angular acceleration and without affecting the angular velocity. If the body is initially moving with constant angular velocity it will continue to do so.

It is possible for a rigid body to experience (1) a net force with zero net torque, (2) a net torque with zero net force, and (3) a net force with a net torque.  The three possibilities are shown in Figures 1, 2, and 3 below (in 2D for simplicity)

In FIG 1 the line of action of the net force is through the center of mass (COM) of the rigid body. It thus produces no net torque about the COM. That means there is no angular acceleration $\alpha$, only translational acceleration $a$ given by Newton's 2nd law for translational motion.

In FIG 3 the line of action of the net force is not through the center of COM. It therefore produces a net torque about the COM. The body therefore has both angular acceleration and translational acceleration per Newton's 2nd law for translational and rotational motion. Any force can be moved to a new location provided its new line of action is parallel to the original, and provided a torque is added about the COM equal to its torque contribution. The equivalent force system is below the figure where $I$ is the mass moment of inertia about the COM.

In FIG 2 there are two equal and opposite parallel forces acting on the body. We call this a "force couple" or simply a "couple". It equals the product of the magnitude of the force and the perpendicular distance between the lines if action of the forces. It provides pure rotation without translation. The net force and translational acceleration is zero. It thus undergoes angular acceleration and no translational acceleration. The equivalent force system for the couple is shown below the figure.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: What will happen to net torque if the net force acting on the object doesn't pass through the line of action ? (Will it be non zero)

Comment: @Prannav Do you mean if the line of action of the net force is not through the center of mass?

Comment: Yes. Line of action of Net force is not passing through the centre of mass.

Comment: @Prannav  OK. I will update my answer to explain

Comment: @Prannav See my update.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following two rules of rigid body motion:

- The net force of a body relates to the linear motion of the center of mass (as single point on the body).
- The net torque about the center of mass of a body describes the rotational motion about the center of mass.

So regardless if the body is rotating or not, if the center of mass is accelerating, then there is a *non-zero* net force applied.